# Nextjs: server rendered code blocks highlighted by Prismjs mismatches and causes re-render due to leading whitespace on class attribute

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, mismatch, prismjs

I am trying to implement server-side rendering of syntax highlighted (tokenized) code blocks using Prismjs (note: I know how to do this using client-side rendering via `useEffect` and `refs`, and I got this working using [prism-react-renderer](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/prism-react-renderer). I am looking specifically for the solution for "bare" Prismjs & SSR).

```
// codeExamples = array of some code strings

const Code = ({ code, language }) => {
  const html = Prism.highlight(code, Prism.languages[language], language);
  return (
    <pre
      data-language={language}
      className={`language-${language}`}
    >
      <code
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: html,
        }}
      />
    </pre>
  );
};

export default function Home() {
  return codeExamples.map((example, i) => (
    <Code
      language="javascript"
      code={example}
      key={i}
    ></Code>
  ));
}
```

It does work to some extent, but I've run into an issue: the code block gets briefly re-rendered, probably because of a **leading whitespace** on the `class` attribute:

- 1st render: `class="language-javascript"`
- 2nd render: `class=" language-javascript`

[image]

This is causing (besides the poinless expensive re-render) a non-pleasant layout shift, temporarily fixed by adding hard-coded `font-size` in pixels to a `<pre>` element.

I've got some occasional warnings, either for server and client props mismatch (can't reproduce right now) or for `Extra attributes from the server: class` – but only when running `next dev`, not while running `next build && next start`.

Tested on the latest versions of Nextjs and Prism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got an answer from a dive into `Prismjs` [source code](https://github.com/PrismJS/prism/blob/master/prism.js):

```
if (parent && parent.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'pre') {
    parent.className = parent.className.replace(lang, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' ') + ' language-' + language;
}
```

This is where the whitespace comes from. It is quite obvious, why it is here (as a padding for string concatenation).

A temporary hacky fix is to add a leading whitespace to a `className` on `<pre>` element as well.

```
<pre
   data-language={language}
   className={` language-${language}`}
>
```

But it is quite clear that this is **not** a good way to use `Prismjs` for SSR.

Comment: It's not just with SSR, SSG (Static Site Generation) is also having the problem. Probably anything with rehydration on the client will get this. I also got the case where class names were switched position... I would add Prismjs uses quite a bad way to manage classes. Either you set it with `className` or you add/remove through `classList`.